# 2D/3D Soft body physics in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, physics, 3d, soft-body-dynamics

I want to implement soft bodies in my game similar to this [link](https://i.imgur.com/mUOUfAU.gif).

I tried using this [Soft body simulation plugin](https://unitylist.com/p/hp9/Soft-Body-Simulation) but it has the following problems:

1. Only works with box colliders.
2. Doesn’t work with Unity’s physics engine i.e. the bodies don’t react to the forces applied.

For my game,

1. The soft bodies should be able to collide and interact with any types of colliders (including mesh collider).
2. The bodies should work with Unity’s physics engine i.e. the bodies should react to the forces and gravity applied.

I am flexible in implementing soft bodies in 2D or 3D.

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic.

Comment: Usually these are implemented as a whole bunch of small colliders spaced-apart by springs. What kinds of shapes do you need for your game?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need very basic shapes like cube, sphere, and cone.

Comment: @DMGregory can you share any tutorial or articles demonstrating your suggestions?

Comment: Just the ones I'm sure you've already found by putting those words into a search engine.

Comment: Thank you @DMGregory. I was able to find tutorials for the approach discussed by you.

Answer (score 1):

The 3D soft bodies can be implemented using spring joints and mesh bones. Assign spring joint to each bone and connect it to all the other bones.

Tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTdKEJpX2HI&feature=youtu.be&t=1088

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as Accepted if it solved your problem.